# Can't install libpq-dev on debian wheezy

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian-wheezy, apt

I already have `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main` in my /etc/apt/sources.list file.

I have tried to follow the dependency trail but I have reached a dead end. This is how it goes:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
(...)
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: krb5-multidev but it is not going to be installed

sudo apt-get install krb5-multidev
(...)
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3) but 1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libk5crypto3 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3) but 1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3) but 1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1 is to be installed

sudo apt-get install libkrb5-3=1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3
(...)
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkrb5-3 : Depends: libkrb5support0 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3) but 1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1 is to be installed
```

And that's where the problem is. If I try to install the libkrb5support0 version it needs it warns me that about 1.6 GB worth of software will be removed including texlive, nautilus, libreoffice or openssh for example. Any ideas?

**Edit**

```
cat /etc/debian_version
7.8
```

---

```
apt-cache show krb5-multidev

Package: krb5-multidev
Source: krb5
Version: 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3
Installed-Size: 687
Maintainer: Sam Hartman <hartmans@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3), libk5crypto3 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3), libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3), libgssrpc4 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3), libkadm5srv-mit8 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3), libkadm5clnt-mit8 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3), comerr-dev
Suggests: krb5-doc
Description-en: Development files for MIT Kerberos without Heimdal conflict
 Kerberos is a system for authenticating users and services on a network.
 Kerberos is a trusted third-party service.  That means that there is a
 third party (the Kerberos server) that is trusted by all the entities on
 the network (users and services, usually called "principals").
 .
 This is the MIT reference implementation of Kerberos V5.
 .
 Most users wishing to build applications against MIT Kerberos should
 install libkrb5-dev.  However, that package conflicts with heimdal-dev.
 This package installs libraries and headers in /usr/include/mit-krb5 and
 /usr/lib/mit-krb5 and can be installed along side heimdal-multidev, which
 provides the same facilities for Heimdal.
Homepage: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/
Description-md5: 7761820aba399b20f00deab931782fe1
Section: libdevel
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/updates/main/k/krb5/krb5-multidev_1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb
Size: 153624
MD5sum: bf887d013aef226d69670372158df179
SHA1: 16f7601ac5e4b55b6860ebc0b72c0fe5102e11ed
SHA256: 79c1c6f379c36f31c0607e46f6bd19ea20a7c66ddaf8dd0474b0c264b74cc480

Package: krb5-multidev
Source: krb5
Version: 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
Installed-Size: 687
Maintainer: Sam Hartman <hartmans@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2), libk5crypto3 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2), libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2), libgssrpc4 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2), libkadm5srv-mit8 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2), libkadm5clnt-mit8 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2), comerr-dev
Suggests: krb5-doc
Description-en: Development files for MIT Kerberos without Heimdal conflict
 Kerberos is a system for authenticating users and services on a network.
 Kerberos is a trusted third-party service.  That means that there is a
 third party (the Kerberos server) that is trusted by all the entities on
 the network (users and services, usually called "principals").
 .
 This is the MIT reference implementation of Kerberos V5.
 .
 Most users wishing to build applications against MIT Kerberos should
 install libkrb5-dev.  However, that package conflicts with heimdal-dev.
 This package installs libraries and headers in /usr/include/mit-krb5 and
 /usr/lib/mit-krb5 and can be installed along side heimdal-multidev, which
 provides the same facilities for Heimdal.
Homepage: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/
Description-md5: 7761820aba399b20f00deab931782fe1
Tag: admin::login, admin::user-management, devel::lang:c, devel::library,
 implemented-in::c, network::client, protocol::kerberos,
 role::devel-lib, security::authentication, security::cryptography,
 use::login
Section: libdevel
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/k/krb5/krb5-multidev_1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2_amd64.deb
Size: 153496
MD5sum: 98b229beff22debe70d1deb61f965f23
SHA1: 56c8c197fd2511ba7c72b20d66a78087351dc24d
SHA256: 354ec830b64b33f750ce21b10ec84238d62847a4601b5392cab0da95b76d8d5d
```

---

```
apt-cache policy krb5-multidev

krb5-multidev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3
  Version table:
     1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 0
        500 http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

---

```
apt-cache policy libkrb5-3

libkrb5-3:
  Installed: 1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1
  Candidate: 1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u3 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 0
        500 http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running wheezy? cat `/etc/debian_version`. `apt-cache show krb5-multidev` and `apt-cache policy krb5-multidev" please.

Comment: I am, `cat /etc/debian_version`: 7.8. I've edited the question to include the rest.

Comment: OK, interesting. Also `apt-cache policy libkrb5-3` please.

Comment: I've just added it.

Comment: You seem to have manually installed a newer Kerbros via local `dpkg` commands, not from a repository. It didn't install `krb5-multidev`, which `libpq` requires. The older `krb5-multidev` in Debian is not compatible with the newer Kerberos libs you installed, so it refuses to install. You might be able to uninstall the newer `libkrb5-3` and other libraries `krb5-multidev` conflicts with using `apt-get remove`, but this might also remove packages that depend on these, possibly software you still use and wish to keep. Check the changes `apt-get` proposes before saying yes.

Comment: As I said, I have already tried downgrading the packages. However, too much software depends on them, apt-get proposes removing over 1.6 GB of packages when trying to downgrade libkrb5-3.

Comment: Did you make apt install from the [experimental branch](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental) at some point? (that's what `1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1` suggests)

Comment: Well, in that case you're going to have to get `krb5-multidev` from the same place you got the rest from. You've got your system in a weird state where there are a bunch of packages that come from no currently configured repository, so it can't fetch additional packages from it, but they conflict with packages from the repos you do have configured.

Comment: I did install Python 3.4 from the experimental branch, that's probably where all this comes from. I have already tried to install krb5-multidev from the sid branch but I had similar problems. Maybe I'll try again. I don't suppose there's a good way to clean it without breaking everything, no?